# join two views and detect missing entries where the matching condition is in the next row of the other view/table (using SQLITE)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am running a science test and logging my data inside two sqlite tables.
I have selected the data needed into two seperate and independent Views (RX and TX views).

Now I need to analyze the measurements and create a 3rd table view with the results with the following points in mind:

1- For each test at TX side (Table-1) there might be a corresponding entry at RX side (Table-2).

2- If the time stamp @RX side is less than the time stamp at the **next row** of the TX table view
we consider them to be **associated** with one record in the 3rd view/table and calculate the time difference OTHERWISE it would be a miss.

Question: How should i write the sql query in SQLITE to produce the analysis and test result given in table3?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
TX View - Table (1) 
id | time         | measurement
------------------------
1  | 09:40:10.221 | 100
2  | 09:40:15.340 | 60
3  | 09:40:21.100 | 80
4  | 09:40:25.123 | 90
5  | 09:40:29.221 | 45


RX View -Table (2)
time         | measurement
------------------------
09:40:15.7   | 65
09:40:21.560 | 80
09:40:30.414 | 50

Test Result View - Table (3) 
id |TxTime          |RxTime        | delta_time(s)| delta_value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 09:40:10.221   | NULL         |NULL         | NULL (i.e. missed)
2  | 09:40:15.340   | 09:40:15.7   |0.360        | 5
3  | 09:40:21.100   | 09:40:21.560 |0.460        | 0
4  | 09:40:25.123   | NULL         |NULL         | NULL (i.e. missed)
5  | 09:40:29.221   | 09:40:30.414 |1.193        | 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function `LEAD()` to get the next `time` of each row in `TX` and join the views on your conditions:

```
SELECT t.id, t.time TxTime, r.time RxTime,
       ROUND((julianday(r.time) - julianday(t.time)) * 24 * 60 *60, 3) [delta_time(s)],
       r.measurement - t.measurement delta_value
FROM (
  SELECT *, LEAD(time) OVER (ORDER BY Time) next 
  FROM TX 
) t 
LEFT JOIN RX r ON r.time >= t.time AND (r.time < t.next OR t.next IS NULL)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d7a962701c9d66c55ef8b4a7e13d2193).
Results:

```
> id | TxTime       | RxTime       | delta_time(s) | delta_value
> -: | :----------- | :----------- | :------------ | :----------
>  1 | 09:40:10.221 | null         | null          | null       
>  2 | 09:40:15.340 | 09:40:15.7   | 0.36          | 5          
>  3 | 09:40:21.100 | 09:40:21.560 | 0.46          | 0          
>  4 | 09:40:25.123 | null         | null          | null       
>  5 | 09:40:29.221 | 09:40:30.414 | 1.193         | 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (complete answer with working demo). Is there any solution to this without  using the window function?

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7c1b65d8b81b80dcb079f5c8faae8a3c

Comment: Note for other users: in cases where sqlite ver < 3.25 (no window function support) this answer will help (e.g. SQLiteStudio uses sqlite ver 3.24.0, for now). Thanks again.

Comment: @qwa This is why I prefer DB Browser for SQLite. Its latest release uses SQLite 3.32.2 and I hope soon the new version to support 3.33.0